# Change date separators in php

Tags: php

Hello I have a form where I insert a date in gg / mm / yyyy format when the mold changes to yyyy / mm / gg format but I want that even if I write gg-mm-yyyy it prints me anyway yyyy / mm / gg how could I do it? Maybe with a simple if?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: <div class="content_form">
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['invio'])) {
    ?>
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <label>Inserisci la tua data di nascita</label>
        <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="GG/MM/AAAA">
        <input type="submit" name="invio" value="Invio">
    </form>

    <?php
} else {
    $prova=explode('/', $_GET['data']);
    echo $prova[2]."/".$prova[1]."/".$prova[0];
}

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
date('d-m-Y')
```

for the current date, or

```
date('d-m-Y', $unix_timestamp)
```

for a specific unix timestamp. The output will like so:

```
31-10-2020
```

Comment: could there be a str_replace?

Comment: str_replace('-', '/', $_GET['data']) would also work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). It works like explode except it lets you split on a Perl compatible regular expression.

Something like this would split on either / or -:

```
$prova=preg_split('#(?:/|-)#', $_GET['data']);
echo $prova[2]."/".$prova[1]."/".$prova[0];
```